# Get crypto-currency price at a timestamp without limits

Tags: api, historical-trade-data

I'm trying to get the price of a crypto-currency at a specific timestamp. So I used the API cryptocompare :

https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#

For example :

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD&ts=**mytimestamp**

This solution works well but I have some issues related to the limitation of the API.

I need to get the price more than 26k times and unfortunately this API won't let me do as many requests.

It returns me this error :

> {"Response":"Error","Type":99,"MaxLimits":{"Minute":300,"Second":15,"Hour":8000},"Message":"Rate
>   limit
>   excedeed!","Aggregated":false,"Data":[],"YourCalls":{"hour":{"Histo":16},"minute":{"Histo":16},"second":{"Histo":16}}}

Do you have a solution to avoid that ? Is there a way to get all the prices in only one request ?

Someone as mentionned that on reddit : https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6xbwxp/ethereum_price_history_api/

But I didn't find how to do it.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?